# How to properly update the Spark SQL catalyst jar in a cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I recently made some customized changes to the Spark SQL catalyst module to avoid some query planning issues (join order issues).

Now I have to upload the spark-catalyst.jar to the cluster. Ideally, I should have all the nodes in the cluster have identical related jar files.

However, in theory, is it also possible to just update the the spark-catalyst.jar of the node in which the driver program runs on?
(My underlying cluster is AWS EMR, so the driver runs on the application master node)

I did the experiment: just update the application master node and it seems work (based on the Spark UI DAG). I just want to confirm this is valid and does not have side effects during development.

Thank for the clarification.